# Can you unpack a tuple into a struct? And vice versa?

Tags: solidity, struct

Let's say I have a struct:

```js
    struct NetworkConfig {
        bool myBool;
        uint256 myNum;
    }
```

And I have it saved as a variable as such:

```js
NetworkConfig public activeNetworkConfig;
```

If I were to call the `activeNetworkConfig` variable from another function, it would get returned as a tuple of `(bool, uint256)`.

Is there a way for me to "unpack" it into a struct?

For example:

```js
contract OtherContract{
  MyContract public myContract;

  struct NetworkConfig {
        bool myBool;
        uint256 myNum;
    }

  function getMyContractNetworkConfig() public returns(memory NetworkConfig){
    return myContract.activeNetworkConfig();
  }

}
```

Right now, we'll get an error for `getMyContractNetworkConfig`.

Here is a full contract example:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract MyContract {
    struct NetworkConfig {
        bool myBool;
        uint256 myNum;
    }

    NetworkConfig public activeNetworkConfig = NetworkConfig({myBool: true, myNum: 1});
}

contract OtherContract{
  MyContract public myContract;

  struct NetworkConfig {
        bool myBool;
        uint256 myNum;
    }
   constructor(address myContractAddress){
        myContract = MyContract(myContractAddress);
   }

  function getMyContractNetworkConfig() public returns(NetworkConfig memory){
    return myContract.activeNetworkConfig();
  }

}
```

And here is the error we get:

```
from solidity:
TypeError: Different number of arguments in return statement than in returns declaration.
  --> PriceConverter.sol:25:5:
   |
25 |     return myContract.activeNetworkConfig();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

First, add `memory` to `returns(NetworkConfig)`, so `returns (NetworkConfig memory) { ...`. That should get you past the compiler error.

There will also be a runtime error because you have cast `myContract` as `MyContract` but you haven't instantiated it at an address.

Typically, `MyContract` would be deployed, so do that first and note the address. `OtherContract` is going to need that information.

Consider something like:

```
constructor(address myContractAddr) {
  myContract = MyContract(myContractAddr);
}
```

If you miss that step, then it will look for it at `address(0)` and it won't be happy with what happens.

If both contracts are in agreement about the shape of the `struct` (so far, they are) then things should work as expected.

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

It turns out it seems to be unhappy about the "free" getter function from `public`. I don't know why, so possibly a kind soul will chime in about ABI/compiler subtleties that seems to be in play here.

Using a simple explicit getter, structs are indeed passed around without issue.  This works:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract MyContract {
    
    struct NetworkConfig {
        bool myBool;
        uint256 myNum;
    }

    NetworkConfig private activeNetworkConfig = NetworkConfig({
        myBool: true, 
        myNum: 1});

    function networkConfig() public view returns(NetworkConfig memory) {
        return activeNetworkConfig;
    }
}

contract OtherContract{
    MyContract public myContract;

    constructor(address myContractAddress){
        myContract = MyContract(myContractAddress);
    }

    function getMyContractNetworkConfig() public view returns(MyContract.NetworkConfig memory) {
        return myContract.networkConfig();
    }

}
```

You cannot assign the value of one type of `struct` to another type of `struct` even if the layouts are identical ("not implicitly convertable").

For example:

```
struct Thing1 {
    bool foo;
    uint bar;
}

struct Thing2 {
    bool foo;
    uint bar;
}
```

You won't be able to:

```
Thing1 memory t1 = Thing1({ foo: true, bar: 42 });
Thing2 memory t2 = t1;
```

You would have to:

```
Thing1 memory t1 = Thing1({ foo: true, bar: 42 });
Thing2 memory t2 = Thing2({
    foo: t1.foo,
    bar: t1.bar
});
```

Comment: Thanks! And yeah sorry was just shipping pseudocode to get the question... but you're right it does make it tricker to answer. I updated the question with code that actually compiles. We still get that error there even with the constructor addition.

Comment: I think the answer just might be "no, you currently can't do this?"

Comment: @Patrick got me curious. See updated answer.

Comment: Oh quiet interesting indeed! Looks like even if the structs are the same, they are still considered different by solidity... that's actually probably for the best. You'll have to specify which struct in which contract you want.

Answer (score 1):

My solution of this problem bellow

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract MyContract {

    struct NetworkConfig {
        bool myBool;
        uint256 myNum;
    }

    NetworkConfig public activeNetworkConfig = NetworkConfig({myBool: true, myNum: 1});
}

contract OtherContract{

    struct NetworkConfig {
        bool myBool;
        uint256 myNum;
    }

    MyContract public myContract;

    constructor(address _myContract){
        myContract=MyContract(_myContract);
    }


    function getMyContractNetworkConfig() public view returns (NetworkConfig memory){
        (bool myBool, uint myNum) = myContract.activeNetworkConfig();
        return NetworkConfig(myBool,myNum);
    }
}
```